# How to add bike ride to an array with return answer

Tags: javascript

How I can Add Bike ride the 3-5-2019 to my calendar - and it should respond with "Bike ride added to your calendar". Should add an event represented by an object with keys "name" and "date" to an array of events.

```
let TodoList = [];
const name = [];
const favoriteDish = [];
const eventsList = [];
//############## Greeting #####################//
function getReply(command) {
  const splitString = command.split(' ');
  if (command.includes('Hello') && name.length === 0) {
    const grabName = splitString.slice(-1);
    name.push(grabName);
    return 'Nice to meet you' + ' ' + grabName;
  } else if (command.includes('Hello') && name.length !== 0) {
    return 'repeted twice';
  } else if (command.includes('What is my name')) {
    return 'your name is ' + name[0];
  }
  //##### Add fishing to my todo and Add singing in the shower to my todo #####// 
  else if (command.includes("Add") && command.includes("my todo")) {
    const task = splitString.slice(1, -3).join(' ');
    TodoList.push(task)
    return task + " added to todo list";
  }
  //##################### Remove fishing to my todo ###########################// 
  else if (command.includes("Remove") && command.includes("my todo")) {
    const task = splitString.slice(1, -3).join(" ");
    if (TodoList.includes("task")) {
      TodoList.splice(TodoList.indexOf(task), 1);

      return task + " removed from todo list";
    }
    return "Removed " + task + " from your todo";
  }
  //############################# What is on todo? ############################// 
  if (command === 'What is on todo?') {
    return TodoList;
  }
  //########################## What day is it today? #########################//
  else if (command.includes('today')) {
    const d = new Date();
    const month = d.getMonth() + 1;
    const day = d.getDate();
    const output = d.getFullYear() + '-' +
      (('' + month).length < 2 ? '0' : '') + month + '-' +
      (('' + day).length < 2 ? '0' : '') + day;
    return `Today is ${day}. of ${month} ${output}`;
  }

  //################################# maths #################################//
  if (command.includes('Multiply', 0)) {
    const x = splitString.slice(-1).join(' ');
    const y = splitString.slice(4, 12).join(' ');
    const Multiply = x * y;
    return 4 * 12;
  }
  //############################# My favorite dish ##########################//
  else if (command.startsWith('My favorite', 0)) {
    favoriteDish.push(splitString);
    favoriteDish.splice([0][4], 1, "Lasagne");
    return `Saved favorite dish as ${favoriteDish}`;
  }
  //########################## What is my favorite dish ####################//
  if (command === 'What is my favorite dish?') {
    return favoriteDish;
  }
  //########################## Set a timer for 4 minutes ##################//
  else if (command.includes('timer for 4 minutes')) {
    const minutes = splitString.slice(-2, -1);
    setTimeout(_ => console.log("Timer done"), 1000 * 60 * 4)
    return `Timer set for ${minutes} minutes.`;
  }
}
console.log(getReply('Hello my name is Axel')); // Nice to meet you Axel
console.log(getReply('Hello my name is Axel, Hello my name is Axel')); //Hey Axel You repeated your name twice 
console.log(getReply("Add fishing to my todo"));
console.log(getReply("Add singing in the shower to my todo"));
console.log(getReply("Remove fishing from my todo"));
console.log(getReply("What is on todo?"));
console.log(getReply("What day is it today?"));
console.log(getReply("Multiply"));
console.log(getReply("My favorite dish is spaghetti"));
console.log(getReply("What is my favorite dish?"));
console.log(getReply("Set a timer for 4 minutes"));
```

Comment: Use the [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) function.

Comment: Only post one question at a time. The two tasks are completely unrelated. You also have made no attempt to solve any of the tasks.

Comment: Ok, sorry for that I just updated my question

Comment: What happened to the timer question? That's the one you got an answer to, now the answer makes no sense.

Comment: Actually it is working with a waiting time ,so the completev result can be done. Do you have an idea how I can do so That the timer can show automatically "Timer set for 4 minutes" "Timer done" with no waiting time. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sets your time for 4 minutes after 4 minutes you get your message

```
function getReply(command) {
  if (command === 'What is my favorite dish?') {
    return favoriteDish;
  } else if (command.includes('timer for 4 minutes')) {
    setTimeout(_ => console.log("Timer done"), 1000*60*4)
    return `Timer set for ${minutes} minutes.`;
  }
}
```

Comment: how I can do so That in console.log the timer  can show automatically "Timer set for 4 minutes" "Timer done" with no waiting time. Thanks.

Comment: @AxelEkamba do you want those to print at the same time? If not then I'm unsure of what you want

Comment: Yes, Exactly. I want it to print at the same time.

Comment: What does this have to do with the edited question?